# Name for ASP/ASP.NET Short Tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp-classic

Is there a particular name for  `<%` and  `%>`.

Comment: Thanks all. Selecting Robotsushi's answer over David. Although David provided the correct answer, "Code Nuggets" is just easier to pronounce lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scott Gu calls these Code Nuggets. 
So thats what I go with.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 6):

`<%  %>` is usually referred to as a "server-side code block" or "code rendering blocks".

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickstartV20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx

Which is different from `<%#  %>`, which is a "databinding code block"

and `<%$  %>` is an 'expression code block'. (introduced in .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 3):

They were nick named a long  time ago as Yellow Tags, because of how Visual Studio highlighted them in yellow.

Comment: Best one I heard was "bee stings",because of the yellow and black color, and the point of the < or >.

Comment: @Moose I hadn't heard that one.  That is a good one.  I'll have to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are just called delimiters.