# How to extract a php variable from a variable inside <%= %>

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a child theme and I need to replace some files in the parent theme, to create some new functions. When I come across this type of code where you use <% %>. I have no idea what they do or how they work in the syntax. I need to write it almost like this. They have using a if statement in the echo, and I cant understand how they "et_pb_showcase_tax" is the selected taxonomy. So how do I get "et_pb_showcase_tax" to be $current_taxonomy?

Code:

```
$get_taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
if($get_taxonomies){
    echo '<select id="et_pb_showcase_tax">';
    foreach ( $get_taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        echo <<<END

<option value="$taxonomy"<%= typeof( et_pb_showcase_tax ) != 'undefined' && '$taxonomy' == et_pb_showcase_tax ?  ' selected="selected"' : '' %>> $taxonomy </option>

END;
    }
    echo '<select>';
}
```

Anything would be help full!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Those are [ASP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088207/name-for-asp-asp-net-short-tags). Since you appear to be using PHP, you must convert its logic to PHP.

Comment: I am not really familiar with ASP, are you saying it can be done to convert it to just a normal PHP variable?

Comment: They *look like* ASP tags, but ASP tags containing what appears to be JS in the middle of a PHP WordPress template wouldn't make a lot of sense, so there must be more to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is either broken, or designed to be run through some pre-processor.

The contents of the ASP-style tags (`<% ... %>`) looks like JavaScript (the check for `typeof(x)` matching the string `'undefined'` is how you detect an uninitialised variable), but the way it's mixed into the PHP and HTML makes no sense.

It's possible that the person who wrote the WordPress theme based it on some ASP code, and didn't properly check for leftover code.

However, I'm at a loss to explain how it would ever be possible to compare a PHP value with a JS one and have the result simply echo an HTML attribute to the right place - the PHP must run first to echo the value of `'$taxonomy'`, but then it will also have echoed the whole `<select>`, so it will be too late to insert attributes into the middle of it. I conclude that this code is either magic, or nonsense.

Comment: I know it's really strange to code it like this. But if the code above can do it, I must available to get out a variable of what it's understanding right?

Comment: @Fredrik That depends which possibility is true: if it's magic, then you can harness that magic for your own ends. If it's nonsense, then hdhgjhxhdgthhgff. :P

Comment: @Fredrik More seriously, you really need to find some documentation for how this code works, rather than trying to guess, or asking us to guess.